# What conjugation of what word is 出なく?

Tags: verbs, conjugations

牛からミルクが**出なくなって**

I'm having trouble working out the conjugation of the bold characters. I assume that なって is the -te/connective form of なる... but what the heck is **出なく**?

Logic tells me it should be some form of 出る... but I don't know which.

So... can anyone tell me where that 出なく came from? Is it just a typo of 出なくて? Or am I completely misreading this and it's actually a different word altogether?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At first, I was just going to comment on your comment on the other answer, but maybe a different approach is better.

We can look at this two ways. If we build it up, it goes like this:

1. 出る - to come out
2. 出ない - to not come out
3. 出なく - a "stem" form conjugation of 出ない (Japanese verbs and adjectives [share some conjugation rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_equivalents_of_adjectives#i-adjectives)) *such* that it can be put in front of another verb. [not really sure how it would translate it English maybe "not coming out" ?]
4. 出なくなる - to start to not come out. (possibly in the future).  Here we are adding the helping verb なる (= to become)
5. 出なくなって - it is starting to not come out *or* it has started to not come out [continuative form of naru to express a state of not coming out]

So 出なくなって is the て-form of the helping verb なる when it's helping 出ない [the negative form of 出る]

出なくて means something slightly different. It means "it's not coming out." and is the て-form of 出ない

The difference being that　出なくなって indicates a **change** has occurred where it *was coming out* and now *is not coming out* whereas 出なくて indicates merely that it is *not coming out*.

So if tried to milk a cow and nothing ever came out, 出なくて but if you milked a cow and it stopped providing milk, then 出なくなって.

In other words, 出なくなって is not a verb sequence. It's a verb plus a helping verb. If you're looking for it in Tae Kim, then it's [here](http://www.guidetojapanese.org/surunaru.html).

Comment: Thanks for that excellent answer. I think I get it now. **Negative** verbs can be conjugated in the same way that i-adjective adverbs can (**い** --> **く**) when they're being linked to なる or する. The meaning is then roughly "to become X" or "to decide to do X", where X is the 1st verb. e.g. **見えなくなった** = "[it] _became_ NOT visible". And if you want to do the same thing with **positive** verbs, you use ことに or ように, e.g. **見えるようになった** = "[it] _became_ visible". In contrast, **見えなくてなった** = "[it] _is_ not visible _and_ became...". Am I correct?

Comment: Yep. That sounds right to me.

Comment: You are confusing te-form and 連用形.   The 連用形 of なる is なり and not なって.

Comment: 勉強になりました。 is it fixed now?

Comment: @Hyperglyph three comments: First, for affirmative verbals, the こと and よう constructions are [different](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/42581/%E3%81%93%E3%81%A8%E3%81%AB%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B-versus-%E3%82%88%E3%81%86%E3%81%AB%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B/42591#42591). Second, direct-style negative verbals and adjectivals are equivalent grammatical forms (i.e. they don't just conjugate the same - they are actually the exact same thing). Third, this adjectival construction has a parallel with nominals as you demonstrated with こと・よう (i.e. that's actually a nominal pattern: nominal + に +  なる).

Answer (score 14):

なって is indeed the te form of なる.

出なく is the morphing of 出ない (the negative form of 出る) to allow it to be connected to another verb.
so 出ない　＋　なる becomes 出なくなる (to start not coming out)
Adding the te form to the end is just a way of connecting it to another sentence.

This can be done to connect any verbs, for example 食べない (negative of 食べる) could become 食べなくなる (to start not eating / stop eating)

So in your example, 牛からミルクが出なくなって would be "The milk stopped coming out (started to not come out) of the cow, and..."

Comment: Thank you for the answer. A follow-up question, if I may... your description of  出なく sounds (to my un-educated ears) like a description of the negative -te form, which I learned as 出な**くて**. Is 出なく a completely different connective form (and if so, does that form have a name)? Or does Japanese have a rule for dropping the ending **-て**?

Comment: http://www.guidetojapanese.org/learn/complete/verb_sequences <- Link to Tae Kim's guide on conjugating negative te- form (where I learned it)